# range of RFID tag and scanning to receiver

Tags: rfid

What is the maximum range of active RFID tag and receiver today and how many **RFID tags** can be scanned through **RFID reader** at unit time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends.Active tags works on 2.4GHz.Awarage read distance is about 50-100 meters. some strong readers reads about 200 meters. but it depends on readers power. For EU; allowing only 2W power for reader antennas. if you increase power, reader distance will increase.